# How do I get emmet support for react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am currently working on a React Native project that uses TypeScript as the programming language. I am familiar with using Emmet in my text editor for web development and would like to know if it is possible to enable similar functionality for React Native development with TypeScript.

I have managed to make Emmet work for normal react but not react native because it isn't normal JSX.

Are there any specific plugins or configurations that I need to be aware of to enable Emmet support for React Native development with TypeScript?

Comment: If you are willing to switch to VS Code Emmet is baked into the [editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet). I have accidentally triggered Emmet in many react native projects (I dont know the first thing about Emmet so every time I have triggered Emmet it has been completely accidental), so at least for the version baked into VS Code, react native is Emmet compatible

Comment: After using Emmet twice it has occurred to me that it would be really cool if a package exist that could convert some of the query selectors over to something more suitable for react native. Like  `div.container` maps to `<div className="container"></div>`. It'd be nice if there was some other character  could be used to signal the style prop like if `View..container` mapped to `<View style={styles.container}></View>`.

Comment: I guess you could use [nativeWind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativewind) and then Emmet would be more compatible with react-native components

Comment: @PhantomSpooks Thanks it works on vscode insiders. It doesn't support custom components but that's ok